# Mysql Query Update From php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

Hi to everyone i have a problemn with a query in PHP to Update records.

```
 <?php
include('../webcgo/script/cox.php');
$query = $cox->query("SELECT cf_id FROM offerte;");
while ($idx = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $check = '<button class="uk-button" onclick="location.href=\'http://localhost/chartscript/remRegola.php?dis=2&id=' . $idx['cf_id'] . '\'">OK</button>';
    $query_check = 'UPDATE offerte SET check=\'' . $check . '\' WHERE cf_id=' . $idx['cf_id'].';';
    if ($queryx = $cox->query($query_check) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $cox->error;

    }
}
mysqli_close($cox);?>
```

The result:
Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check='

Comment: And if you echo `$query_check` you get?

Comment: `check` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). If you're going to use it in your query you *must* wrap it in backticks:

```
 $query_check = 'UPDATE agoragroup_chronoforms_data_inserimento_offerte_prod SET `check`=\'' . $check . '\' WHERE cf_id=' . $idx['cf_id'].';';
```